# How can i find the smallest number in array while getting the element number

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a problem that keep bugging me out. Finding the smallest number in array is easy but here is my problem; when you find the smallest number in array , the smallest number becomes **a[0]** th element of array. 
What i want is , i want to find the smallest number and also which element it is. Such as this

```
a[0]   a[1]   a[2]   a[3]
 5      20     1      12
```

I want my code to write `1 is the smallest number and it's a[2] element of array`

I just want to get the **2** from there so i can use it in rest of my code. Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you guys.

Edit : i tried this way before

```
int[] dizi = {5 , 12, 20, 1};
    int gecici;


    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for (int y = 1; y<4; y++) {

            if (dizi[i] > dizi[y]) {

                gecici = dizi[i];
                dizi[i] = dizi[y];
                dizi[y] = gecici;

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: could you post what you have tried? *Finding the smallest number in array is easy but here is my problem; when you find the smallest number in array , the smallest number becomes a[0] th element of array.* did you... sort your array..? sorting cost more compared to just checking who and where is the smallest element.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. It is really not clear what your problem is. If you have code that gives unexpected results, please include that code with your question.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I just edited my post about what i tried. I'm really amateur at opening posts in here. I hope you guys excuse me

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.com/dZVXTt4b), for your homework. but do remember Stackoverflow is not for code generation.. some people will just shun such post.. happy coding! keep learning new stuff, ok. also, your example looked like a bubble sort. no wonder the array reordered..

Comment: Thank you. I just wanted to learn , i don't even know why did i got downvoted but sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could leverage `IntStream.range` in such case:

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
         .mapToObj(index -> new SimpleEntry<>(index, arr[index]))
         .min(Comparator.comparingInt(SimpleEntry::getValue));
```

example:

```
int[] arr = new int[]{5,20 ,1 ,12};
IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
         .mapToObj(index -> new SimpleEntry<>(index, arr[index]))
         .min(Comparator.comparingInt(SimpleEntry::getValue))
         .ifPresent(s -> System.out.println(s.getValue()+ 
               " is the smallest number and it's index" + s.getKey() + "of array"));
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It does work ! But i guess i have to learn about InStream though. Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] arr = {3,66,22,44,55};
int small=arr[0];
int index=0;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
     if(arr[i]<small){
            small = arr[i];
            index = i;
     }
}
```

Comment: It's not work  for the array {3,0,22,44,55} . and  make `small = arr[0]`.

Comment: Much thanks for answering but it doesn't work it seems

Comment: `int small=arr[0];` try by changing this line. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int[] a = {5, 20, 1, 12};
IntStream.range(0, a.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> i)
    .min(Comparator.comparing(i -> a[i]))
    .ifPresent(i -> System.out.printf(
        "%d is the smallest number and it's a[%d] element of array%n", a[i], i));
```

If your array is double then

```
double[] a = {5, 20, 1, 12};
IntStream.range(0, a.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> i)
    .min(Comparator.comparing(i -> a[i]))
        .ifPresent(i -> System.out.printf(
            "%f is the smallest number and it's a[%d] element of array%n", a[i], i));
```

You can do it in a method.

```
/**
 * Returns min index of array x.
 * (Returns -1 when length of array x is zero)
 */
static int findMinIndex(int[] x) {
    return IntStream.range(0, x.length)
        .mapToObj(i -> i)
        .min(Comparator.comparing(i -> x[i]))
        .orElse(-1);
}
```

And call like this.

```
int[] a = {5, 20, 1, 12};
int minIndex = findMinIndex(a);
System.out.printf("%d is the smallest number and it's a[%d] element of arraay%n",
    a[minIndex], minIndex);
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. It works on integer but let's say my array is double, how can i make this work?

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate your help

Comment: Hey ermmm i'm really sorry for my ignorance but i have one more last question,  how can i take the i from out of there? Because i will use it in another place.

Answer (score 1):

```
int [] array = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int smallestNum=array[0];
int smallestIndex=0;
for(int i=1;i<array[i];i++){
   if(array[i] < smallestNum){ //if you want the last small number then use `<=` (if small number occur multiple times)
      smallestNum = array[i];
      smallestIndex=i;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for every elements beginning from smaller to larger and their corresponding indices then you can do as follow:

```
public class Test {
    public static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
        int value;
        int index;
        public Pair(int _value, int _index) {
            this.value = _value;
            this.index = _index;
        }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Pair that) {
            return Integer.valueOf(this.value).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(that.value));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] a =new int[]{5, 20, 1, 12};
        int n = a.length;
        Pair[] p = new Pair[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) p[i] = new Pair(a[i], i);
        Arrays.sort(p);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            System.out.println(i + "th minimum is "+ p[i].value +" and is located at index "+ p[i].index);
        }
    }
}
```

The complexity of above method will be of time complexity `O(n log n)`. But, If you require to know only the minimum one and it's index , then you can easily retrieve it in `O(n)` time complexity as follows:

```
   int[] a =new int[]{5, 20, 1, 12};
    int n = a.length;
    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE, minIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (minValue > a[i]) {
            minValue = a[i];
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Minimum value is : "+ minValue+ " and it is located at index: "+ minIndex);
```